# c# http post data with parameters and save it to mysql

Tags: c#, php, mysql, post

I use this code in c# app to post data:

```
    void postdata()
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        var URI = new Uri("http://my-real-address.com/test.php");
        string myParameter = "?parameter=test";
        wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        wc.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc__UploadStringCompleted);
        wc.UploadStringAsync(URI, myParameter);
    }

    void wc__UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Result);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString());
        }
    }
```

and content of test.php:

```
<?php
$save = $_GET['parameter'];

//db auth settings
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'password';

if ($save != "")
{
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    if(! $conn )
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (parameter) VALUES ('$save')";
    mysql_select_db('database');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $retval )
    {
        die( mysql_error() );
    }
    mysql_close($conn);
}
?>
```

I don't know why but c# app just open MessageBox without any text and data is not stored in mysql database. But If I and open same url with parameters in web browser everything works great.

I am not sure if:
string myParameter = "?parameter=test"
is correct so I tried chaning it to:
string myParameter = "parameter=test"
but I get same results.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a parameter, not an uri-extension. So get rid of the question-mark.

```
void postdata()
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        var URI = new Uri("http://my-real-address.com/test.php");
        //string myParameter = "?parameter=test";
        string myParameter = "parameter=test";    // <---------- !
        wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        wc.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc__UploadStringCompleted);
        wc.UploadStringAsync(URI, myParameter);
    }
```

Everything else looks good to me.